# Best way to identify the file type is executable in groovy

Tags: groovy, processbuilder

I  have a path variable and wanted to check given path is executable file or not

```
           boolean isExecutable = false
            def process = ("file " + "/abc/xyx/abcd.sh").execute()
            log.info("printing the output: ")
            process.text.eachLine {
                if (it.contains("executable")) {                   
                    isExecutable = true
                } 
            }

if(isExecutable){
println "file is executable"
}
```

With the above code I am able to find out whether that file is executable or not. But just wanted to know that is there any other alternatives to find out the file type in groovy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def file = new File('/abc/xyx/abcd.sh')
println file.canExecute()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But in case if we pass a directory instead of the file then that case this is giving true for example path is '/abc/xyx' in this case also it is returning true.

Comment: do `file.isFile() && file.canExecute()` then